# Store files with various formats in SQL Server using Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have following files placed in folder in my local machine:

```
1. MyPDfFile.PDF
2. MyWordDoc.Doc and MyWordDoc.docx
3. MyHTMLfile.html
```

I am trying to pull these files and store it in SQL Server using Python. The data type of column which shall store files is `varbinary`. But, my code is unable to perform this task. All it stores is name of file and not actual file content. Please can anyone help me with storing these files in database.

My Python code:

```
FILEList = {}
FilePath = 'C:\\SampleTestFiles\\'
FilePath = os.listdir(FilePath)
for FILE in FilePath:
    FILEList[FILE] = FILE

for File, Fileobject in FILEList.items():             
    if File.endswith('.pdf'):
         file = FILEList[File]
    elif File.endswith('.doc') or File.endswith('.docx'):
         file = FILEList[File]

myfile_name = FILE
myfile = FILEList[File]

Query = """
INSERT [dbo].[files] ( [file_name],[file]) values (?,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),?))
        """

values = (file_name, file)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(Query, values)
cursor.close()
conn.commit()
print(File, "Files inserted..")
```

Comment: Generally databases are best for data and the file system is best for files. You shouldn't store file content inside your SQL Database, instead keep the files in a directory and store the full path in your table.

Comment: The requirement is to store the files in 'Files' table so that they can be referred for future processing. Agreed with you suggestion. But I need  solution for this task.

Comment: That's why I did not posted as an answer.